# Make hapi plugin available in modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, hapi.js

I'm refactoring my Hapi server to use reusable modules instead of performing logic in my route handlers. I have a plugin registered in my Hapi server for MongoDB connection pooling, which I'd like to be able to access in these modules. Is there a way to export the server object itself, or do I need to rewrite my modules to accept the request object as an argument? I'm using node 0.12.12 and Hapi 8.4.0.

I already tried `module.exports = server;` in the file where my server is defined, and then requiring the server object from a different file, (both with `var server = require('../index.js').server;` and `var server = require('../index.js')(server);`, but I either get an error or `undefined`.

The closest thing I could find to an answer was this issue from a few years ago, on an older version of Hapi: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/1260
- but it looks like this was never really resolved.

Comment: If you have `module.exports = server` then it'd just be `var server = require('../index.js')`

Answer (score -1):

Well, I'm an idiot, but maybe this will help somebody else out:

It seems module.exports cannot be called within a callback, according to the node documentation. So I moved this statement to the bottom of my index.js:

`module.exports.server = server`

And then in my other modules, called:

`var server = require('../index.js');`

And was able to access the plugins contents as `server.server.plugins`

HTH